# :only-child not showing in Webkit/Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
    section{
        display: none;
    }
    section:only-child {
        display: block;
    }   
</style>
<body>
    <section>This should be visible</section>   
</body>
</html>
```

I believe that the text 'This should be visible' should be visible! This is also the case in Firefox. Firebug, as well as Safari's Web Inspector think so as well.

However, if you open the page in Safari (OSX and iPhone), the text is not showing. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code, also with a doctype, and with a non-HTML5 element (a div). All webkit browsers I could test had issue: Safari-on-Windows 5, Chrome Windows, Chrome Linux, Epiphany-webkit.

When I changed from display states to background colours, however, webkit worked fine. Changing other display states like float also worked fine.

This is very likely a bug (though I didn't see one via search engines, but I did not search bugs.webkit.org) purely to do with changing display states. It also works fine if the element is first set to block and :only-child is set to none, so it would specifically be overriding the display: none. Opening element inspectors seems to trigger the CSS display which remains until refresh.

Your code (if you add a doctype too) seems to be a pretty good test case. If this bug isn't already on bugs.webkit.org you could submit this code.

*edit okay I definitely have Javascript on, still don't see the ability to have this be a comment rather than an answer, which is what I originally intended.

Comment: From memory you can comment on your own question or answers all the time, but to comment on other people's you need 50+ rep...

Comment: Skuld,thanks. I should've looked at the FAQ, it's prolly in there. :)

Comment: No worries :) We were all new once, besides TBH this is more an answer than a comment, plus it's got you some rep :)

Comment: I found this bug on bugs.webkit.org. It's quite old and I'm not sure if it's the same issue. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33479. Should I resubmit it?

Comment: Jhu: your bug seems slightly different. Many CSS3 bugs only affect dynamically-added elements, but yours is hitting static ones, and this is :only-child, not necessarily the same problem as :first-child. You could ask there (with your reduced test case) if your bug is similar (if it's a duplicate someone will link it). I see this bug you linked is "uncomfirmed" and (was) only on a Nightly. Your bug is on a released stable (several in fact). Worth submitting!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found this workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxAnH/

```
section {
    height: 0;
    overflow: none;
}
section:only-child {
    height: auto;
}
```

It wouldn't hide the elements margins but as a wrapper it could be enough to hide some elements. Did you found another workaround?